# How to display IBM BPM snapshot environment variables using wsadmin?

Tags: snapshot, business-process-management, wsadmin, ibm-bpm

I need to display all existing environment variables for snapshots installed on BPM. Is there a way I can do this using the wsadmin command ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a wsadmin command to display all existing variables for a snapshot. If this is something that would be useful, I would suggest opening a Request for Enhancement(RFE) with BPM development for their consideration. Here is a link on how to do this:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/175980/how-do-i-submit-an-enhancement-request-or-rfe-for.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paula, there is no wsadmin cmd to display env variables.

However, you can check out:

BPMSetEnvironmentVariable:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.6/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/rref_bpmsetenvironmentvariable.html

And REST call to get env variable:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSV2LR/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/rest/bpmrest/rest_bpm_wle_v1_system_env_variable_get.htm

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the BPM REST Interface APIs.

Use this API to retrieve the list of process applications, in which you can find the ID of the snapshot you are interested in.

```
https://<bpm_host_or_ip>:9443/rest/bpm/wle/v1/processApps
```

Use this API to retrieve the envrionment variables and their default values.

```
https://<bpm_host_or_ip>:9443/rest/bpm/wle/v1/processAppSettings?snapshotId=2064.11a398d0-c6b8-41e4-b8eb-daaef864be14"
```

You can easily use `jq` in a Linux environment to parse out the information you are interested in.

Finally use this API to retrieve the current value of a given environment variable.

```
https://<bpm_host_or_ip>:9443/rest/bpm/wle/v1/system/env/variable?processAppAcronym=<APP_ACRONYM>&name=<ENV_VAR_NAME>
```